# Can I call react component in a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm just start learning react js. Just wondering is it a good way to invoke a component inside another component?

Answer (score 1):

Most React projects will start out by giving you an `App.js` component where you can start writing code. There, you can invoke other components using [JSX syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). Like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Working example below:

```js
// Main application component
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

// Header component
function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>My first React App</h1>
    </header>
  )
}

// Main component
function Main() {
  return (
    <main>
      <p>Stuff and stuff go here..</p>
    </main>
  )
}

// Footer component
function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer>
      <p>Copyright 2020</p>
    </footer>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Note: You may also see class components instead of functional ones. They look something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      // some state goes here..
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to compose components using JSX. There is a good write up on the react docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

```
const ComponentOne = () => <div>hi</div>

const ComponentTwo = () => <div>two</div>

const ComponentThree = () => (
  <>
    <ComponentOne />
    <ComponentTwo />
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

React has two type of components: Function based and Class based. I will explain Function based components.

> Example:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

function ComponentB(){
    return (
      <p>Hello i'm component B</p>
    )
};//end;
function ComponentA(){
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1>hello i'm component A</h1>
        <ComponentB />
      </Fragment>
    )
};//end;
export default ComponentA;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explain. After reading some of the answers I realized my confusion came from not understanding the differences between import function as component vs. import react component class(class extend component). Do I need to worry about which type of component I construct or they act mostly same.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you want to learn, or start to le I recommend this https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html. If you have another question please let me know.